# Is there a pattern to Draven's Spinning Axes?

Tags: league-of-legends

The newest champion in *League of Legends*, Draven, has an ability called Spinning Axes. It increases the damage of your next basic attack and bounces into the air. If you are able to catch it before it hits the ground, the effect lingers, increasing every attack until you fail to catch said axe. You can have two of these going at one time.

The only problem with this is, in the heat of battle, the axes become very difficult to keep track of when they go flying every which way.

**Is there any way of predicting which direction these axes will go upon launch? Or is it completely random?**

<sub>Note: I realize it leaves an indicator on the ground. I'm wondering if it is possible to predict *where* that indicator will appear.</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From what I have read, watched, and experienced, this is how it seems to work:

When stationary, the axes will either come right back to you or go slightly left or right of the way you are facing. It appears to have a fairly good chance of just bouncing back to you, but don't count on this as it can be debatable.

When moving, it will always go ahead of you in whatever direction you are facing after the axe hits.  You can use this to your advantage to try and plan where the axe will land by quickly clicking to move a different direction before it hits.  Its landing can be altered by terrain as well.

Quick note about when you have two going, none of the above are affected.  It is just like a normal Spinning Axe, but there are two of them! :P

Answer (score 4):

"Spinning axe will lead draven so if he is standing still it will land cloase by and if he is running it will fall along his path." - Champion spotlight

You questions is if there is any way to predict where it will land.
So by running in a direction before activating you know it will fall in your path. 
Soruce: [Champion spotlight](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5zyGj4Z0Sg)

Comment: The game tries to predict your movement and lands close to where it thinks you're going.

Answer (score 2):

- When you stand still, it will fall very close to you
- When you move forward, it goes forward with you
- When you move backward, it goes backward with you
- When you move to the side, it will fly in either direction

Answer (score 0):

Randomly? I think not.
The only time it goes randomly is when you stand dead still for too long or within baron and dragon pit. Other than that it's 100% controllable. Right-click behind you as you farm to propel the axe in the opposite direction of farm and away from danger.

Comment: It isn't random within the baron/dragon pit...

Answer (score -1):

Draven's axes land randomly, but can kind of be predicted. This is a very interesting mechanic, and is high risk/high reward since it could possibly land somewhere that puts you out of position.

Its actually a very simple mechanic; it falls in a small AOE around where Draven is pathing to the moment it bounces off the opponent.

I personally do not like this mechanic on AD carries, and I do not expect to see Draven in High ELO games for a while. I think these AD carries need to be consistent with their damage.

However, the fact that he is an extremely unique AD carry makes solo queue fun.